# How do I sum the dimensions of a space?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From the [wikipedia page on diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Matrices_that_are_not_diagonalizable/#characterization)

> An $n\;x\;n$ matrix $A$ A over a field $F$ is diagonalizable if and only if the sum of the dimensions of its eigenspaces is equal to $n$

My question is, how do I sum the dimensions of the eigenspace or any space for that matter..

Say my column space of a $3x3$ matrix is...

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I "sum the dimensions?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of vectors corresponding to each eigenvalue forms a subspace.  You are to take the dimension of each of these subspaces and add them up to see if it adds to the dimension of the whole space.  For example, $$\begin {pmatrix} 2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1 \end {pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues of $1,2$.  The space corresponding to $1$ is vectors proportional to $(0,0,1)^T$.  The space corresponding to $2$ is the one spanned by $(1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0)^T$.  The sum of the dimensions of these subspaces is $1+2=3$, which is the dimension of the whole space.  The matrix is diagonalizable, as can be seen because it is diagonal.

By contrast, $$\begin {pmatrix} 2&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1 \end {pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues of $1,2$.  The space corresponding to $1$ is vectors proportional to $(0,0,1)^T$.  The space corresponding to $2$ is the one spanned by$(1,0,0)^T$.  The sum of the dimensions of these subspaces is $1+1=2$, which is less than the dimension of the whole space.  The matrix is not diagonalizable.  I haven't proven that, but the theorem promises it.

Comment: I think you want $(1,0,0)^T$ for the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: and you're getting those dimension vectors by finding the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$, right?

Comment: @ChrisCuster: Yes, thanks.

Comment: @deltaskelta:  yes that is right

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @RossMillikan's excellent answer ...

In general, all we can say about the dimension of the sum of two vector subspaces $V$ and $W$ is that it is greater than or equal to $\max\{\dim V, \dim W\}$ and less than or equal to $\dim V + \dim W$.

However, if $V$ and $W$ are eigenspaces with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_V$ and $\lambda_W$ then we know that the only vector they have in common is $0$ (can you prove this ?) and so we can say that

$\dim(V+W) = \dim V + \dim W$

Different eigenspaces have different eigenvalues, so this is why we can simply add the dimensions of eigenspaces to find the dimension of their sum.